# Difference between a `vector` created from the std `<vector>` library, and an `STL vector` created from: `<stl_vector.h>`

Tags: c++, vector, std, header-files

#### Why are there two different vector libraries in the STD library?

---

1. `stl_vector.h`
2. `vector.h`

***What's the difference between the two?***

Comment: You will find _a lot_ of implementation specific header files other than `std_vector.h`  if you look around. For reference: [A list of the standard C++ headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header).

Comment: `stl_vector.h` is shorthand for `stl_vector_implementation_detail_do_not_include_directly.h`.

Comment: A header is not a library. It will start making sense once you get a more thorough understanding of how primitive the header mechanism is.

Comment: @molbdnilo you really understood where I am at "understanding-wise". It helped me rethink how the entire C++ system works. The libraries are built from many files. That's why sometimes the libraries I include — via the `#include` preprocessor — will have a `.h` appended to it, which was something I didn't understand before now. In  a nutshell. An STL Library is a HEADER file, but its part of an entire build that makes up the **`<vector>` Library**. Anyhow, I thought you'd find it satisfying that you helped to bring me clarity.

Comment: @JΛYÐΞV in many implementations `vector` is a file consisting of a list of `#include`s . File extensions are optional

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look [into the file](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h) itself you will see

```
/** @file bits/stl_vector.h
 *  This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
 *  Do not attempt to use it directly. @headername{vector}
 */
```

Your code should not directly include `stl_vector.h`. It's an implementation detail of libstdc++ and could be absent in other standard library implementations.

Comment: You should `#include <vector>` and only `<vector>`.